# Seeking complete code examnple for JQuery/Ajax Ping with success/fail

Tags: ajax, jquery

Since it is asynch and there may be several in parallel I would prefer a solution which supports multiple parallel requests and knows which success/fail belongs to which request - probably using The jqXHR Object as described at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (?).

Since I am just learning, a complete code example which I can study and understand would be most welcome.

Comment: Define 'fail'. Will a failure be determined based on Http Status code, network error, missing/invalid value in response, other type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5's [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) will allow you to have a multi threaded solution in JS. If you're willing to experiment with them, they're supported in Opera, Chrome and Firefox (haven't tested it on IE yet). Check them out.